# Azure DevOps : Building Visual Studio Solution containing mixture of .Net 6 and .Net Framework projects

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, .net-4.0, .net-6.0, .net-framework-version

I am stuck on an issue building my solution containing .NET 6 project and .NET Framework (4.0 and 4.6.1) projects on Azure DevOps build pipeline (with dotnet build and msbuild task).
I cannot use windows-2019 as build agent coz of .NET 6 and unable to make work windows-2022 coz of .NET framework < 4.8
anyone come across this and know how you/they tackled this situation please?

Upgrading .NET Framework option is an expensive approach time-wise.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Continuing on the older versions of .Net Framework will be increasingly untenable. Support for .Net Framework 4 ended on January 12, 2016. Support for .Net Framework 4.6.1 for most OS versions ended on April 26, 2022. Also see [.NET Framework Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-framework). Note that one of the issues you are running into is that SHA-1 is no longer considered secure and that is why many organizations will not allow Windows Server 2012 and why Windows Server 2022 doesn't allow .Net Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps : Building Visual Studio Solution containing mixture of .Net 6 and .Net Framework projects

Just as you know, the .NET Core SDK and .NET Framework supported by `Windows 2019` are:

[image]

And the .NET Core SDK and .NET Framework supported by `Windows 2022` are：

[image]

So, you could not use the hosted agent `Windows 2019` or `Windows 2022` to build your mixture projects.

As workaround, you could create your private agent to install the .NET 6 and .NET Framework (4.0 and 4.6.1) SDK on your local machine, if you do not want to upgrade .NET Framework:

[Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)